# logrotate exact syntax to run cron job

Tags: cron, logrotate

All over the Internet there is the exact information on configuring your `logrotate` file, but not a single post on the syntax for the `crontab`.

I think it should be something like this, but I am not sure:

```
0 0 1 * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

or this:

```
0 0 1 * * /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

Is either correct?